# PHP Form is being submitted with different values in POST?

Tags: php, html, post, submit

I am currently trying to build a signup form using HTML/PHP. For some reason the password that I input is being replaced with a saved password upon post and I'm not sure why.

The code for my signup form:

```
            <form autocomplete="off" name="signupform" action="includes/signup_function" method="POST">
                <label>First Name: </label>
                <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname">
                <label>Last Name: </label>
                <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname">
                <label>Username: </label>
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email"></br></br>
                <label>Password: </label>
                <input type="password" autocomplete="new-password" id="pwd" name="pwd"></br></br>
                <label>Confirm Password: </label>
                <input type="password" autocomplete="new-password" id="passwordconfirm" name="passwordconfirm"></br></br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit"></input>
            </form>
```

I am simply doing a password match, and it is returning false -- my debug values are showing completely different to what I input and the password post is returning a saved cpanel password.

```
        $firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
        $lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $password = $_POST["pwd"];
        $passwordconfirm = $_POST["passwordconfirm"];

        if(matchPassword($password, $passwordconfirm) !== true) {
            header("Location: ../signup?err=password=");
            exit();
        }

    function matchPassword($password, $passwordconfirm) {
        $result;
        if($password == $passwordconfirm) {
            $result = true;
        } else {
            $result = false;
            error_log("password invalid: " .$password.",".$passwordconfirm);
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

If I input the password as Alex -- the form posts with Password as H9wL^X938*i (the saved password) and Confirm Password as Alex.

Debugging to Error Log shows this - (The password inputted to the form is Alex)
`[22-Nov-2023 15:59:09 Australia/Sydney] password invalid: H9wL^X938*i,Alex`

I've never encountered this before, hopefully someone can help me, TIA.

Comment: `If I input the password as Alex -- the form posts with Password as H9wL^X938*i (the saved password) and Confirm Password as Alex.` using autocomplete it may occur

Comment: I would advice against using `autocomplete="new-password"` because [it is only supported by Firefox](https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_global_attributes_autocomplete_new-password).

Comment: I don't think there is any use case where you want `autocomplete` on a password input?

Comment: @Don'tPanic The idea behind `autocomplete="new-password"` is that the browser could help the user to create a new password. The user could have installed a plugin that takes care of this fully automatically. But all the stars need to align for this to happen.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware thanks, I was not aware of this. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#preventing_autofilling_with_autocompletenew-password

Comment: Thank you guys, I only added the autocompletes in an attempt to prevent this from happening -- I read somewhere that this may fix, but issue still occured.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the issue might be related to the browser's password autofill feature. When you set autocomplete="off" on your form, it may not completely disable password autofill in some browsers. Instead, you can try using autocomplete="new-password" specifically for the password fields.

Update your form to include autocomplete="new-password" for both password fields:

```html
<form autocomplete="off" name="signupform" action="includes/signup_function" method="POST">
    <!-- ... other fields ... -->
    <label>Password: </label>
    <input type="password" autocomplete="new-password" id="pwd" name="pwd"></br></br>
    <label>Confirm Password: </label>
    <input type="password" autocomplete="new-password" id="passwordconfirm" name="passwordconfirm"></br></br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"></input>
</form>
```

By using autocomplete="new-password", you signal to the browser that these fields are specifically for entering a new password, and it may help to prevent interference from autofill features.

If the issue persists, you might want to check if any browser extensions or settings are affecting the behavior. Additionally, you can try testing your form in different browsers to see if the problem occurs uniformly or if it's browser-specific.

Comment: My form already includes autocomplete="new-password" on both fields. I also thought it would prevent it, but issue is persisting, I'll have a dig through settings.

Comment: OP's code already does what you suggest.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. It looks like you've been away for a few years so this might be a good time to refamiliarise yourself with the site rules, including the one that [bans](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1) the use of "AI" tools.